# How do I configure Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger levels per namespace?

Tags: c#, logging, configuration, scope, .net-core-2.2

I want to be able to configure the nested levels like Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/DataProtection independently of just Microsoft.*, is this possible, if so how do I do it?
The logging works and I see currently see everything at debug but nothing is excluded.

I'm injecting the settings etc into a class which is configured in Program.cs like this

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory);

builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true);

var envName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(envName))
    builder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.${envName}.json", true);

builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
builder.AddCommandLine(args);

var configurationRoot = builder.Build();

new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel(options =>
        { options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null; })
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseConfiguration(configurationRoot)
    .ConfigureLogging(lb =>
     {
         lb.AddConsole();
         lb.AddDebug();
         lb.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
     })
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .Build()
    .Run();
```

with Startup.cs injecting the logger and config like

```
public Startup(ILogger<Startup> iLogger, IConfiguration iConfiguration)
{
    _configuration = iConfiguration;
    _logger = iLogger;
    _logger.LogDebug("Configured logger, config and builder.");
}
```

with logging config in appsettings.json like

```
"Logging": {
  "IncludeScopes": true,
  "LogLevel": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection": "Warning",
    "Default": "Debug"
  }
}
```

Coming from log4j I'd attempt something like the above but it's not working, where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Change your appsettings.json to include the full namespace e.g. `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "Warning"`.

Comment: I've tried that as both
    ```"LogLevel": {
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection": "Warning",
      "Default": "Debug"
    }```
and `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.*"` and neither worked.

Comment: I don't think you need `builder` the code in `startup.cs` as configuration etc. are loaded by `WebHostBuilder.Build()`. What happens if you remove that?

Comment: Yeah I realised that probably belongs in Program.cs so it can parse args etc. I'll update the code above.

Comment: Can I suggest you take a look at the [setup a host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2#set-up-a-host) page to understand what needs to go in `program.cs`.

Comment: Yes, that helped immensely.

However, through the rabbit hole I also found this https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/255 which notes the (now) preferred way to setup logging.

If you want to submit those two as the answer I'm happy to mark it answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the [how to setup a host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2#set-up-a-host) page to understand what needs to go into the `program.cs` code. This has changed for .Net Core 2.x and has reduced the amount of code we need to load the settings and setup logging.

Comment: Changes in 2.x are documented here https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/255